# Changing date system in Pycharm/IntelliJ Platfrom Live templates

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

Whenever I create a Python live template with a variable set as `date()`, the date comes in an american format, meaning `(MDY)`, I want it in `(DMY)`. How can I achieve this?

I've already tried looking for a date settings dialogue box in Pycharm, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From official online help at http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html

`date()` -- Returns the current system date in the specified format.

**By default**, the current date is returned in the **default system format**. However, if you specify date format in double quotes, the date will be presented in this format:

[image]